# Apache Cassandra good for a "hashtags"

Tags: database, cassandra

I want to integrate a Twitter/Instagram like Hashtag-System in a webapp. 
But I have some problems with the technical concept, because the system should be very scalable. Therefore I will use cassandra as database.

**How looks an efficient database design for storing Hashtags in a Cassandra database**

Comment: an Opinion based question will get you opinion based answers. This is not the site for it mate :)

Comment: Ok then I will change the question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would create a schema like the following one:

```
CREATE TABLE tweet (
    user_id varint,
    tweet_id timeuuid,
    tweet_text text,
    hashtags set<text>,
    PRIMARY KEY (user_id, tweet_id)
) WITH CLUSTERING ORDER BY (tweet_id DESC);

CREATE INDEX idx_tweet_hashtags ON twitter.tweet(hashtags);
```

Then you can issue queries as follows:

```
-- Latest tweets by hashtag
SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE hashtags CONTAINS '#2' AND tweet_id > maxTimeuuid('2014-12-20 00:00+0000');

-- Latest tweets by user
SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE user_id = 1 AND tweet_id > maxTimeuuid('2014-12-20 00:00+0000') ORDER BY tweet_id DESC;

-- Latest tweets
SELECT * FROM tweet WHERE tweet_id > maxTimeuuid('2014-12-20 00:00+0000') ALLOW FILTERING;
```

Note the latest query is doing a "filtering", so it could be "slower" than the others.

Comment: sadly the first and third queries are very unpredictable and therefore should be considered slow. This is because secondary indexes are only indexed on a single node level and the partition key is omitted here. On a large cluster this means that potentially all nodes have to be queried. Read more about this problem [here](https://pantheon.io/blog/cassandra-scale-problem-secondary-indexes)